# как поверх одного изображения закрепить другое

Tags: html, css

Как поверх одного `img` закрепить другой тоесть у меня есть 2 картинки одна обычная аватарка, вторая - канцелярская кнопка, как закрепить кнопку поверх картинки

```html
<img alt='аватар' class='pin_img' src='$myrow2[avatar]'><br>
<img class='pin' src='../img/pin.svg'><br>
```

кнопка должна быть сверху-справа

Comment: Кто пробовали? С какими проблемами столкнулись?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Пример:***

```css
#container {
    position:relative;
}

#img1 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

#img2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/b/be/Logo_Fanta.png" id="img1" />
    <img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/pepsi-icon-10.png" id="img2" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Так вроде бы**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 30px;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url(http://webbankir.com/docfiles/skrepka.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://tpkblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/20091017163722Jakes_Avatar_with_gun.jpg">
</div>
```

> http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/WxWVNL?editors=110